# Using Image Magick Convert to Change Channel Depth?

Tags: linux, command-line, conversion, imagemagick

I want to change an image depth of bitmap for testing purposes. Right now I am trying to get a 2 bit palette image, and a 4444 Hicolor image.

I have a true color bitmap. I used the below command line

```
convert -depth 2 /media/bitmap/rule.bmp lut2bpp.bmp
```

then when I used identify I got this

```
Image: lut2bpp.bmp
Format: BMP (Microsoft Windows bitmap image)
Class: PseudoClass
Geometry: 720x480
Type: Palette
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: RGB
Channel depth:
Red: 8-bits
Green: 8-bits
Blue: 8-bits
```

It changed it to a palette which is great, how do I get to change channel depth?

How about changing that true color 24 bit image to hi color 4444 image?

Comment: Not answering the question, but still: `convert wizard: -depth 24 bmp3:wiz.bmp` was yielding 8 bits-per-pixel image for me (ignoring the `-depth 24` flag), but `convert wizard: -colorspace rgb bmp3:wiz.bmp` generated a 24-bits-per-pixel file correctly.